# How I can return false?

Tags: javascript

How I can return false if user.name < 2?

https://jsfiddle.net/q6en1cd2/

```
const user = new Users();
user.name = 'Aa';
```

Comment: Add "length" to your sentence and it becomes : How I can return false if user.name length < 2? --> `if(user.name.length < 2) return false` TADAAAAA

Comment: Please add the relevant code as text to the question itself.

Comment: "Return false" *to where*? If `name` is a setter, and you want to ensure no name shorter than 2 characters can be set, then either don't set the name in the setter (though that's surprising behaviour from the caller's point of view), or *throw an exception*, which would be the right way to indicate an error.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean the length of the `user.name`:

```
if (user.name.length < 2) { return false; }
```

Comment: where it is need write?

Answer (score 1):

Each `String` object has a `length` property you can use:

```
if (user.name.length < 2) {
    // go bananas
}
```

See the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/length/Global_Objects/String).